# Prove $\sqrt{a} \cos^2(\theta) + \sqrt{b} \sin^2(\theta) < \sqrt{c}$ if $a\cos^2(\theta) + b \sin^2(\theta) < c$

Tags: calculus, inequality, convex-analysis, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

Use the concavity of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ to prove that if $a, b,c$ are positive, then $a\cos^2(\theta) + b \sin^2(\theta) < c$ implies $\sqrt{a} \cos^2(\theta) + \sqrt{b} \sin^2(\theta) < \sqrt{c}$

I can prove this using Cauchy-Schwarz, but I am struggling to prove it using concavity of $\sqrt{x}$. Could I get a hint? Please $\textbf{only post hints}$.

Concave means $f''(x)<0$

Comment: Could you clarify the definition of concave function that you have?

Comment: @AleTolcachier I just added it

Comment: Hint: use Jensen's inequality based on concavity of $f$ with $t = \cos^2 \theta$, $1-t = \sin^2 \theta$.  (And then, you do need to also use that $f$ is strictly increasing.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler I am hoping not to use that since it's technically out of the scope of the chapter

Comment: I don't really see any way around it -- in the limit of $c \to (a \cos^2 \theta + b \sin^2 \theta)^-$ the problem pretty much reduces exactly to showing that the secant lines of $f$ lie below $f$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Apply concave inequality
$$f(tx+(1-t)y)\ge tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$$ with $t=\cos^2 \theta$ and$x,y$ well (and easily) chosen.

Comment: It's pretty much immediate after this but I was hoping not to use Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @crystal_math As you’re asking to use concavity, you’re likely to be forced to prove Jensen inequality without saying it from $f^{\prime\prime}\le 0$ for $\sqrt x$ to prove the requested inequality.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** (for another way, not concavity involved)

Define $f(\theta)= a\cos^2(\theta) + b \sin^2(\theta) $ and $g(\theta)= \sqrt{a}\cos^2(\theta) + \sqrt{b}\sin^2(\theta) $.

So taking derivative for the first function and applying the $0$-derivative theorem you obtain that:

$$\max{(f(\theta))}= \max{(a,b)}$$$$\min{(f(\theta))}= \min{(a,b)} $$

But then you can get easily max and min of $g(\theta)$ and you know also $ \max{(f(\theta))} < c $ , so...